# Editing lines in .mk file

Tags: bash

I would like to edit a `.mk` file using Bash.

Inside the file, it looks like this:

```
SRC_PATHS   = src/lib   \
                  src/Application    \
                  src/win   \
                  src/prj
```

I would like to add a new source, which should look like this:

```
SRC_PATHS   = src/lib   \
                  src/Application    \
                  src/win   \
                  src/prj   \
                  src/New
```

I am trying a sed command, but cannot add a new line.

Note: the last src path (`src/prj`) is not always the same.

Comment: `sed -i '/^SRC_PATHS[\t ]*=/{:a;/\\$/{N;ba;};s,$, \\\n\tsrc/New,}' file.mk`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, ill study what this code means.. :D thanks a lot.

Comment: @jhnc Do you know how to check if the last line already has a "\" so that it will not be doubled? Thanks again

Comment: the script shouldn't double but it also won't append the new filename unless it finds a line after `SRC_PATHS=` that doesn't end with \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed` how about:

```
sed -i '$s#.\+#&   \\'\\$'\n''                  src/New#' file.mk
```

Result:

```
SRC_PATHS   = src/lib   \
                  src/Application    \
                  src/win   \
                  src/prj   \
                  src/New
```

Answer (score 1):

If [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s file.mk <<-'EOF'
  $t.
  -1s/$/   \\/
  +s|\(^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\) \(.\{1,\}\)$|\1 scr/new|
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

In-one-line

```
printf '%s\n' '$t.' '-1s/$/   \\/' '+s|\(^[[:blank:]]*\) \(.*\)$|\1 scr/new|' ,p Q | ed -s file.mk
```

---

with a shell variable to store the replacement.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var='scr/new'

ed -s file.mk <<-EOF
  \$t.
  -1s/\$/   \\\/
  +s|\(^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\) \(.\{1,\}\)\$|\1 $var|
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

Remove the `,p` to silence the output to `stdout` , it is there just to see what is the new outcome of the edited buffer.

Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is needed

JFYI, both the script and the one-liner are not limited to just `bash` it should work on any `POSIX` compliant shell.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the indentation of the input and of the desired result, which is not uniform between the first line and the others, I suspect that it is not important at all. If this is the case, then this sed command might work:

```sh
sed -z 's#\n$# \\\nsrc/New\n#' file.mk
```

where

- `-z` is to treat the file as a single line/stream with embedded `\n`s
- `\n$` targets the EOF together with the last `\n`
- the replacement string is  `\\\nsrc/New\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who answered, I tried all your suggestions, and here are the code snippets working and applicable to my needs:

```
sed -i '/^SRC_PATHS[\t ]*=/{:a;/\\$/{N;ba;};s,$, \\\n\tsrc/New,}' file.mk
```

there are some instances where there is already a "\" in the file, so I added new code to clean up those lines

```
sed -i '/^$*.\\/d' file.mk
```

then to add another path in the EOF:

```
sed -i '$s#.\+#&   \\'\\$'\n''                  src/New#' file.mk
```